# How to make an HTTP call to YouTube Analytics API?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, youtube-analytics-api

I want to get information about top keywords driving traffic to my own YouTube channel over the past 7 days. In order to do that, I followed all of the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/authorization/server-side-web-apps). Then I generated a new **access_token** for my account

When I make such a request:

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?dimensions=insightTrafficSourceDetail;7DayTotals&metrics=views&filters=insightTrafficSourceType==YT_SEARCH;channel==MINE&maxResults=10&sort=-views' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer access_token'
```

I receive back an error:

```
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Required",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Required",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "required"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I do wrong when construct this kind of request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Required",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Required",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "required"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Is basically a really bad error message telling that you are missing a required field.

If you check the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query?apix_params=%7B%22dimensions%22%3A%22channel%22%2C%22endDate%22%3A%222019-07-10%22%2C%22ids%22%3A%22channel%3D%3DMINE%22%2C%22metrics%22%3A%22views%22%2C%22startDate%22%3A%222018-07-10%22%7D) you will notice that `startdate and enddate` are required fields.  You have forgotten to add them to your request

Also when you get that far you separate dimensions and metrics with a , not a ;

Comment: You was right about the required query params `endDate` and `startDate`. Also it was necessary to change `;` on `,`. In addition to this I found several other problems

Comment: yes, really bad error message.... trying to figure out how to make a channelsections.update, and seeing this same message.  The documentation is also very unclear on what is required/missing

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in query params, which I set incorrectly. Here is how the URL should be formed in order to get the data from the question:

```
https://youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com/v2/reports?dimensions=insightTrafficSourceDetail&metrics=views&filters=insightTrafficSourceType==YT_SEARCH&maxResults=10&sort=-views&startDate=2019-07-03&endDate=2019-07-10&ids=channel==MINE
```